# What CSS do I need to get this html to appear as it does in the original text?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to represent a two-columned list (two fictitious baseball teams) as it appears in the original text, which looks like this:

[image]

Here is how it actually looks at present (as you can see, 9X uglier than a bag of butts):

[image]

You can see it "live" [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/ey2utqur/67/) at the jsfiddle; it's at the end - in chapter 41. You can either scroll to the end, or get there from the TOC by selecting the Chapter XVI link.

Here is my HTML:

```
<p class="marginalize">     BESSEMERS                   ULSTERS</p>

<p class="marginalize">   KING ARTHUR.                EMPEROR LUCIUS.</br>
   KING LOT OF LOTHIAN.        KING LOGRIS.</br>
   KING OF NORTHGALIS.         KING MARHALT OF IRELAND.</br>
   KING MARSIL.                KING MORGANORE.</br>
   KING OF LITTLE BRITAIN.     KING MARK OF CORNWALL.</br>
   KING LABOR.                 KING NENTRES OF GARLOT.</br>
   KING PELLAM OF LISTENGESE.  KING MELIODAS OF LIONES.</br>
   KING BAGDEMAGUS.            KING OF THE LAKE.</br>
   KING TOLLEME LA FEINTES.    THE SOWDAN OF SYRIA.</p>

<p class="marginalize">                  Umpire--CLARENCE.</p>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.marginalize {
    margin-left: 5em;
    margin-right: 5em;
    color: antiquewhite;
}
```

I don't want it to *look* like a table, even if I must use a table; is that the way to go about this (tablize, without borders)?

Comment: You could use a table or you could try columns in bootstrap if you want the columns to be responsive.

Comment: You can split each column in different `<ul>` and set a equal `width` value to each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your `<p>` tags to `<pre>` tags, it preserves whitespace. Also, your line breaks should be `<br/>` not `</br>`

```css
body {
    background:black;
}
.marginalize {
    margin-left: 5em;
    margin-right: 5em;
    color: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<pre class="marginalize">     BESSEMERS                   ULSTERS</pre>

<pre class="marginalize">   KING ARTHUR.                EMPEROR LUCIUS.
   KING LOT OF LOTHIAN.        KING LOGRIS.
   KING OF NORTHGALIS.         KING MARHALT OF IRELAND.
   KING MARSIL.                KING MORGANORE.
   KING OF LITTLE BRITAIN.     KING MARK OF CORNWALL.
   KING LABOR.                 KING NENTRES OF GARLOT.
   KING PELLAM OF LISTENGESE.  KING MELIODAS OF LIONES.
   KING BAGDEMAGUS.            KING OF THE LAKE.
   KING TOLLEME LA FEINTES.    THE SOWDAN OF SYRIA.</pre>

<pre class="marginalize">                  Umpire--CLARENCE.</pre>
```

Comment: This worked great, but I decided that "pre" does what I was using "marginalize" to do, which just gilded the lily (was too much of a good thing), and I 86'd the "marginalize" jazz. The updated fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/ey2utqur/67/

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping each column in a div with the class marginalize ()". Dividing your content in your code editor is not the same, because the whitespace is **ignored**. So for each column you have to **define** a column. This could be done with two div's, a table with 2 columns, etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <div class='bessemers'>
         <h1>your heading</h1>
          <ul class="float-l">
         <li>your text name</li>
         <li>your text name</li>
         <li>your text name</li>
         <li>your text name</li>
         <li>your text name</li>
         <li>your text name</li>
         <li>your text name</li>
         <li>your text name</li>
         <li>your text name</li>
      </ul>
         <h1>your heading</h1>
      <ul class="float-r">
         <li>your text name</li>
         <li>your text name</li>
         <li>your text name</li>
         <li>your text name</li>
         <li>your text name</li>
         <li>your text name</li>
         <li>your text name</li>
         <li>your text name</li>
         <li>your text name</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
      <div class="umpire">
         <h1>heading</h1>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it should be a table to me. Or at least two floated lists as in kaushik dey's answer.

```css
body{
 background-color:black;}
.marginalize {
 width:550px;
    color: antiquewhite;
 border:none;
 border-collapse:collapse;
 padding:0;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.marginalize td {
 padding:.2em .5em;
}
.marginalize tfoot td, .marginalize th {
 text-align:center;
 padding:1em 0;
 font-weight:normal;
}
```

```html
<table class="marginalize">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>BESSEMERS</th>
      <th>ULSTERS</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>KING LOT OF LOTHIAN.</td>
      <td>KING LOGRIS.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>KING OF NORTHGALIS.</td>
      <td>KING MARHALT OF IRELAND.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>KING MARSIL.</td>
      <td>KING MORGANORE.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>KING OF LITTLE BRITAIN.</td>
      <td>KING MARK OF CORNWALL.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>KING LABOR.</td>
      <td>KING NENTRES OF GARLOT.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>KING PELLAM OF LISTENGESE.</td>
      <td>KING MELIODAS OF LIONES.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>KING BAGDEMAGUS.</td>
      <td>KING OF THE LAKE.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>KING TOLLEME LA FEINTES.</td>
      <td>THE SOWDAN OF SYRIA.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
      <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Umpire--CLARENCE.</td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```